# Rstudio's viewer won't pop up after knitting or compiling for the first time?

Tags: rstudio, preview

When I open Rstudio and knit .Rmd file or compile .Rnw file for the first time, the Rstudio's viewer does pop up. But when I make some change on the source file and try to reknit or recompile it, the Rstudio's viewer won't pop up any more. Or when I try to knit or compile some other source file, the Rstudio's viewer also won't pop up any more.

So, the Rstudio's viewer would only pop up at the first time that I try to knit or compile something. I have to reopen Rstudio to let the Rstudio's viewer pop up.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: do you have spaces in your file name/path?

Comment: No, I don't have spaces in my file name/path. And I find out that this problem only occurs when I try to knit/compile pdf files. The Rstudio's viewer always pops up if I knit a html file.